# I don't understand what the correct form of this inequality is

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality:

$$
(C+Bk)(1-m)+B(m+f)(1-a)>0
$$

I follow the following steps:

$$
(C+Bk)(1-m)>-B(m+f)(1-a)
$$

$$
C(1-m)>-B(m+f)(1-a)-Bk(1-mm)
$$

$$
\frac{C}{B}(1-m)>-(m+f)(1-a)-k(1-mm)
$$

$$
\frac{C}{B}>\frac{-(m+f)(1-a)-k(1-m)}{1-m}
$$

$$
\frac{-C}{B}<\frac{(m+f)(1-a)+k(1-m)}{(1-m)}
$$

Is this correct? But what if I do the opposite, that is:

$$
B(m+f)(1-a)>-(C+Bk)(1-m)
$$

$$
B(m+f)(1-a)>-C(1-m)-Bk(1-m)
$$

$$
B((m+f)(1-a)+k(1-m))>-C(1-m)
$$

$$
B((m+f)(1-a)+k(1-m))>-C(1-m)
$$

$$
B>-C\frac{(1-m)}{((m+f)(1-a)+k(1-m))}
$$

$$
\frac{B}{-C}<\frac{(1-m)}{((m+f)(1-a)+k(1-m))}
$$

They are clearly describing different things so I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what and which result is the correct one. Sorry, not a mathematician, I hope this isn't a very stupid question. C and B are positive(>0), while the other variables are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Can the small variables be exactly 0? And what is the question the inequality is used in? Do you need to find values that satisfy it or do you have to prove it is never true or something else?

Comment: They can be exactly 0. Basically, I'm exploring when a biological trait can evolve (or more likely to evolve) depending on the variables present here. Given the two results give different relationships, I don't understand which one is correct from a mathematical perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both inequalities say that a negative number is smaller than a positive number which is true. This follows from your original equation which also has a positive number on the left and zero on the right. The original inequality doesn't give any information it just says a positive number is greater than zero (except $m=0$ and $a=0$). So anything you follow from that has to be true but you can't learn anything from it. No variable is restricted in any way; it doesn't matter what values you assign to the variables the inequality is true.

You can see that they say the same thing by applying $1/x$ to both sides. Normally this would result in the sign switching, but because one number is negative and the other is positive 1/negative is still negative and 1/positive is still positive, so the sign doesn't switch and you get the same equation for both.

Comment: What if B or C could be either positive or negative? Would that change anything? Would that make on of the results more valid than the other?

Comment: @GWasp If B could be positive or negative you would have to look at two cases: B is positive and B is negative. If B were positive the other variables could again be anything. If B were negative though your second equation would hold, but the first one would be wrong because in the first rearranging you divided by B (which in this case is negative) so you'd have to switch the signs in the first equation to make it true.

Comment: @GWasp so the second equation is true in all cases. It holds if B is negative and if B is positive. Though if B is positive the equation still is true you don't really need the restriction. (You can still use the second equation for both cases)

Answer (score 0):

All your inequalities are correct  if you assume that  $(m+f)(1-a)+k(1-m)$ is also positive but there is no contradiction. Under your assumptions both the inequalities say that  a negative number is less than a positive number (so they say nothing!)

Comment: What if B could be either positive or negative? Would that change anything? Would that make on of the results more valid than the other?

Comment: @GWasp Your inequalities are valid only when  $B$ and $C$ are both positve. You are dividing by $B$ in the first set of inequalities and dividing by $C$ in the second.